# What is the meaning of Views attribute in the file Users.xml in the Stack Overflow data dump?

Tags: support, views, data-dump

I am doing a project on the Stack Overflow data dump. I am unable to understand the significance of the `Views` attribute in the `Users.xml` file.

Can somebody explain it?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5889270/a874), there's a 'x profile views' field. That would be the `Views` attribute you're searching for.

[image]